# How to get the value value of a button clicked Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'll try to be as straight to the point as I can. Basically I using jquery and ajax to call a php script and display members from the database. Next to each members name there is a delete button. I want to make it so when you click the delete button, it deletes that user. And that user only. The trouble I am having is trying to click the value of from one delete button only. I'll post my code below. I have tried alot of things, and right now as you can see I am trying to change the hash value in the url to that member and then grap the value from the url. That is not working, the value never changes in the URL. So my question is how would I get the value of the member clicked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).delegate("#user_manage", "pagecreate", function () {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()   
        var friends = new Array();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        })
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/test/www/user_lookup.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                var $member_friends = $('#user_list');
                $member_friends.empty();

                for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                    $member_friends.append("<div class='user_container'><table><tr><td style='width:290px;font-size:15px;'>" + data[i].username + "</td><td style='width:290px;font-size:15px;'>" + data[i].email + "</td><td style='width:250px;font-size:15px;'>" + data[i].active + "</td><td><a href='#" + data[i].username + "' class='user_delete' data-role='none' onclick='showOptions();'>Options</a></td></tr><tr class='options_panel' style='display:none'><td><a href='#" + data[i].username + "' class='user_delete' data-role='none' onclick='showId();'>Delete</a> </td></tr></table></div>");

                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
                  <script>
                    function showId() {
                    var url = document.URL;
                    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
                    alert(id);
                        alert(url);
                    }
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

IDEAS:

1st: I think it would be easier to concatenate an string an later append it to the DOM element. It's faster.

2nd: on your button you can add an extra attribute with the user id of the database or something and send it on the ajax call. When getting the attribute from the button click, use

```
 $(this).attr('data-id-user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you construct the data in the PHP script? then you can put the index (unique variable in the database for each row) in the button onclick event. So the delete button would be:

`<button onclick = "delete('indexnumber')">Delete</button>`

then you can use that variable to send to another PHP script to remove it from the database.

Comment: Actually writing in freeform script and inline function calls liek that is bad form. He should be using delegate to use the same handler for all of those items (by using a css class selector) and then dynamically forming th ajax request from the user id he could get from the `data-id-user` attribute chepe263 suggested, encoding it in the `id` or by switiching to using a containing `a` tag and creating the URL to stick in the `href`.

Comment: Agreed with @prodigitalson. If you're going to write out the PHP, do it as a data- attribute.

Comment: I'm just really confused by this for some reason I apologize would someone be able to go into further detail for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.user_delete', function() {
     var url = document.URL;
     var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
     alert(id);
     alert(url);
});
```

Comment: I tried something like this however, the value will not seem to add to the url, I click the link and it does nothing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="user_delete" data-id-user="<?php echo $theUsersId ?>"><?php echo $username ?></a>
```

Like wise if you pull down users over json you can encode this attribute like so when you create your markup in the callback function:

```
'<a href="#'+data[i].username+'" data-user-id="'+ data[i].username + '" class="user_delete" data-role="none" >Options</a>'
```

So given what you are already doing the whole scenerio should look something like:

```
$(document).delegate("#user_manage", "pagecreate", function () {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();   
    var friends = new Array(),
        $member_friends = $('#user_list'),
        // lets jsut make the mark up a string template that we can call replace on
        // extra lines and concatenation added for readability
        deleteUser = function (e) {
          var $this = $(this),
              userId = $this.attr('data-id-user'),
              href = $this.attr('href'),
              deleteUrl = '/delete_user.php';

              alert(userId);
              alert(href);
              // your actual clientside code to delete might look like this assuming
              // the serverside logic for a delete is in /delete_user.php
              $.post(deleteUrl, {username: userId}, function(){
                alert('User deleted successfully!');
              });
        },
        showOptions = function (e) {
          $(this).closest('tr.options_panel').show();
        }, 
        userTmpl = '<div id="__USERNAME__" class="user_container">'
                   + '<table>'
                   +    '<tr>'
                   +      '<td style="width:290px;font-size:15px;">__USERNAME__</td>'
                   +      '<td style="width:290px;font-size:15px;">__EMAIL__</td>'
                   +      '<td style="width:250px;font-size:15px;">__ACTIVE__</td>'
                   +      '<td><a href="#__USERNAME__" data-id-user="__USERNAME__" class="user_options" data-role="none">Options</a></td>'
                   +    '</tr>'
                   +    '<tr class="options_panel" style="display:none">'
                   +      '<td><a href="#__USERNAME__" data-id-user="__USERNAME__" class="user_delete" data-role="none">Delete</a></td>'
                   +    '</tr>'
                   +  <'/table>'
                   + '</div>';


    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    })

    $(document).delegate('#user_manage #user_container user_options', 'click.userlookup', showOptions)
      .delegate('#user_manage #user_container user_delete', 'click.userlookup', deleteUser);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/test/www/user_lookup.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            var markup;
            $member_friends.empty();

            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                markup = userTmpl.replace('__USERNAME__', data[i].username)
                          .replace('__ACTIVE__', data[i].active)
                          .replace('__EMAIL__', data[i].email);

                $member_friends.append(markup);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple change you could make:

Replace this part:

```
 onclick='showId();'>Delete</a>
```

With this:

```
 onclick='showId("+data[i].id+");'>Delete</a>
```

And here's the new showId function:

```
function showId(id) {
                    alert(id);
                }
```